# Missing applications in MacTeX

Tags: mac, mactex

I am a complete TeX/LaTeX newbie. I have just installed MacTeX on macOS Catalina.

There is a document called `MISSING APPS.pdf` within `/Applications/Tex`, which mentions that there are 3 apps missing from the installation -- `TeX Live Utility`, `BibDesk` and `cocoAspell`. The document mentions links from where they can be directly downloaded.

**My question is where should these apps be placed/installed after downloading.** Should I just put them in `/Applications`?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to tex.stackexchange, Himanshu. Those applications can be placed anywhere you choose, after downloading.

Comment: CocoAspell is a preference pane and will install itself in the proper place. TeX Live Utility and BibDesk are usually placed in `/Applications/TeX` with the other applications installed by MacTeX but can be placed in other locations.